# php - Time format conversion error

Tags: php, date

This might be a small issue for many but I am not able to solve it.
I am trying to convert date stored in my db and extract day, month and year separately. I have been trying with the following code for conversion and it is returning the value depicting 01 January 1970 for what ever the input date value.
`$item_date_day = date('d M Y', strtotime($item_date));` where `$item_date` is the value from db

**Sample DB Value:** 28 September 15 (Monday)

**Returned date after conversion:** 01 Jan 1970

**Required output:** 28 Sep 2015

Any clue why the conversion is going wrong?

Comment: Plesse add the output of `var_dump($item_date)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime` does not accept this format. Actually the formats accepted by this function is limited. Try this instead:

```
<?php

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F y (l)', $item_date);
    $item_date_day = $date->format('d M Y');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad! It worked the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution, this way you can make sure that not matter what is the last item it will always return the right.

```
 $date_str = '28 September 15 (Monday)';
 $date_arr = explode(' ', $date_str);
 $date_clean = array_pop($date_arr);
 $date = implode($date_arr);
 echo date('d M Y', strtotime($date));
```

This will output

```
28 Sep 2015
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Piil. I just tried your solution and it also worked for me.

Comment: No problem any time mate

Answer (score 0):

The day name in brackets is stopping `strtotime` from working. You could remove it using a regex. Example:

```
$date = '28 September 15 (Monday)';
$date = preg_replace('/(.*) (\(.*\))/', '$1', $date);
echo date('d M Y', strtotime($date));
```